# C# allow on IIS7 ISAPI and CGI Restrictions aspnet_isapi.dll x64 bit

Tags: c#, iis-7, 64-bit, isapi

Is it possible from C# code manipulate IIS7 ISAPI and CGI Restrictions?

The goal is, if on x64 bit machine, check if Framework64/aspnet_isapi.dll allowed, and if not to allow it.

Also, alternatives suggestions will be kindly accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace should contain all the classes you need to modify the iis7 metabase. Here's the MSDN link with all the reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28VS.90%29.aspx

Hope this helps